# How to test a Pyramid application's configuration?

Tags: python, unit-testing, configuration, integration-testing, pyramid

I have a Pyramid application which uses a number of customization on the request object, in particular, and I would like to be sure that my settings are correctly configured and that they are actually configured.

For example, I have the following (simplified for brevity):

```
config = Configurator()

config.add_request_method(lambda self: portal_object, name="portal", property=True)

config.set_default_permission('view')

config.add_request_method(auth.get_user, 'user', reify=True)
```

If these things are not set on the configuration, the application is not going to work, or going to be completely open.

The things I would be interested to test would be:

- the `portal` property that I want to set on the request is the one I passed when configuring the application
- by default, my views have a permission set (so unauthenticated users have a forbidden access)
- my requests always have a `user` property, and this property is cached.

So far, I tried to produce a "real" Pyramid request, which involves copy/paste-ing code from `pyramid.router` (not cool :( ) and, although I haven't tried, I guess it would work if I was setting up something like [WebTest](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WebTest) but I would then test the whole stack, which I'm not so interested at the moment (the views, especially, are already tested separately.)

What are my possibilities to test my application's configuration, and (hopefully) only this?

Answer (score 0):

How about moving the configuration setting part to a separate function and create a unit test against this functinon?